# Correlation basket equities

Tags: correlation, basket

One question: when asking for the correlation of a basket, a trader told me 50% whereas I expected him to give me asset pairwise correlations (i.e. the correlation matrix). What does this 50% mean please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us consider a basket $B$ with components $S_1,\dots,S_n$ :
$$B(t) = \sum_{i=1}^nw_iS_i(t)$$
At time $t$, each component has standard deviation $\sigma_i$, $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, and pairwise correlations are $\rho_{ij}$, $i \not= j$. Thus:
$$\sigma_B^2=\sum_{i=1}^nw_i^2\sigma_i^2+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{1=j}^iw_iw_j\sigma_i\sigma_j\rho_{ij}$$
The **implied basket correlation $\rho_B$** is defined as:
$$\rho_B=\frac{\sigma_B^2-\sum_{i=1}^nw_i^2\sigma_i^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{1=j}^iw_iw_j\sigma_i\sigma_j}$$
It can be interpreted as an "average" pairwise correlation between the components of the basket, and that's what the 50% stands for.

Comment: No worries. Don't hesitate to accept it @Cedric_W.

Comment: Another way to say it is: if all the correlations $\rho_{ij}$ were equal to a common value $\rho_B$ then this value could be found by the formula above.